# get the first line of a contentEditable div

Tags: jquery, html, contenteditable

```js
$('.btn').click(function(){
let arr = $('#parent').html().split('\n');
let first = arr[0];
console.log(first);
});
```

```css
.parent{
background:gold;
min-height:99px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='parent' id='parent' contentEditable></div>
<br>
<button class='btn'>CLICK</button>
```

Pls enter any multiline text inside `parent`.

First line (or block) should be divided by `Enter (keycode 13)`.

I need **only the first line** in console.

So click the `btn`.

Result: **entire html**.

Btw why is just the first line without `div` tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your split to use `split('<div>')` instead of `\n`. You can further remove all the `&nbsp;` that will be added in the `contentEditable` text:

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  let arr = $('#parent').html().split('<div>');
  let first = arr[0].replace(/&nbsp;/g,'');
  console.log(first);
});
```

```css
.parent {
  background: gold;
  min-height: 99px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='parent' id='parent' contentEditable></div>
<br>
<button class='btn'>CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the first line of the Div you can use:

```
var text = $('#parent').clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

**Demo**

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  var text = $('#parent').clone().children().remove().end().text(); // get text
  console.log(text);
});
```

```css
.parent {
  background: gold;
  min-height: 99px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='parent' id='parent' contentEditable></div>
<br>
<button class='btn'>CLICK</button>
```